# Can I create MutableState properties in a ViewModel but expose them as immutable to screens in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

In my ViewModels I have properties that are `MutableState` and I only want to change their `.value` inside the ViewModel but not in the screens.

This is easily fixed by having two properties like this

```
private val _someScreenState = mutableStateOf("something")
val someScreenState: State<String> = _someScreenState
```

But when having a lot of properties this becomes annoying look at and confusing to work with. So is there a way to do the same thing but without having to instatiate two `State` properties?

I know kotlin has a nice way of writing getters and setters for properies inside classes for example like this

```
var someScreenState = mutableStateOf("something")
    private set()
```

This would do the trick since the property itself is a `var` (mutable) while having a private setter. But with compose's `State` I'm not trying to change the property itself but rather it's `someScreenState.value` property so you would still be able to change `someScreenState.value` outside of the ViewModel.

I've used state objects like a `ScreenState` class which holds all the `State` properties inside, but a lot of properties have to be of type `StateFlow` and with state objects you can't pick and choose which is `State` and which is `StateFlow` (there are other problems with state objects as well that's why I've been trying to move away from them).

Answer (score 5):

This is possible using the new experimental Kotlin backing property changes.
This feature requires Kotlin 1.7, a new K2 compiler, and some changes to enable it.

It would be something like this.
(This may not be the exact syntax as it is experimental as there have been a lot of discussions around this for a long time)

[image]

Related article
https://nikoladespotoski.medium.com/overriding-backing-property-type-in-kotlin-1-7-5581cd30e77a

Related GitHub issue for full discussion reference,
https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/278

YouTrack issue link
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14663

Comment: That would be interesting

Answer (score 4):

You can write like this:

```
var state by mutableStateOf("something") //Type is String
    private set
```

Note that I am using kotlin delegation here, you will get type `String` instead of `MutableState<String>`, combine it with `private set`, now you have your object as `var`, you can set it directly inside the viewmodel, and it will be immutable inside your composables, and you still able to observe `state` changes this way. I think it is also more cleaner to use as you can access the value directly without `.value`

However, it worths mention that `by` delegation only works on compose `State`, it does not work with `StateFlow`

**Example:**

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var textFieldValue: String by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    fun onTextFieldValueChange(newValue: String) {
        textFieldValue = newValue
    }
}
```

Composable:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Screen(viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    )  {
        OutlinedTextField(
            label = { Text(text = "Enter your name") },
            value = viewModel.textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = { value -> viewModel.onTextFieldValueChange(value) },
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result image]

As you see, I was able to observe the text field value changes, changes successfully reflected on the composable

Comment: The delegation returns the data and not a state. So it would not be observable. (Date changes will not be reflected in the composable)

Comment: You can see the IDE auto inferred data type here to check this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMwwA.png

Comment: @Abhimanyu, They are actually still observable, when you set the data in the viewModel, it will reflect on the composable.

Comment: How would a non-observable data type be observable in composable? Can you please share an example?

Comment: Well, I have used them this way for a long time, but I will try to share an example

Comment: @Abhimanyu, I have provided an example

Comment: It may seem impossible, because how can the Composable "know" it's dealing with State?, but Compose can do some code generation at *compile time*.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBahaml, Thanks for sharing the example. I have never done this and still do not understand how this works under the hood. I got to know something new today .

Comment: @Tenfour04, I think the same thing, there is something works under the hood.